# Dialog Error async Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

> ---android.app.Dialog.class Exception
>     -------sendDismissMessage();
>
> Activity bizlead.carlife.Transmission has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42407878
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity bizlead.carlife.Transmission has
>   leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42407878
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:355) at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289) at
>   bizlead.carlife.HttpPostTask.onPreExecute(HttpPostTask.java:85) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534) at
>   bizlead.carlife.Transmission.exec_post(Transmission.java:402) at
>   bizlead.carlife.Transmission.access$4(Transmission.java:373) at
>   bizlead.carlife.Transmission$2.onClick(Transmission.java:317) at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5092) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
>   at
>   bizlead.carlife.UploadAsyncTask.doInBackground(UploadAsyncTask.java:57)
>   at
>   bizlead.carlife.UploadAsyncTask.doInBackground(UploadAsyncTask.java:1)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

```
@SuppressWarnings( {"deprecation", "unused"} )
public class Transmission extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

    private final static int BT_COUNT=5, TV_COUNT=6, HYAKU=100, TARGET_WIDTH=300, TARGET_HEIGHT=300;
    private int saveCount, callCount, orderCount;

    private final static int BT_ID[]=
    {    R.id.bt_trans1,
        R.id.bt_trans2,
        R.id.bt_trans3,
        R.id.bt_trans4,
        R.id.bt_trans6
    };

    private final static int TV_ID[]=
    {
        R.id.tv_trans1,
        R.id.tv_trans2,
        R.id.tv_trans3,
        R.id.tv_trans4,
        R.id.tv_trans5,
        R.id.tv_trans6
    };

    private final static String BT_NAME[]=
    {
        "場所変更",
        "個人情報変更",
        "車両情報変更",
        "カメラ起動",
        "決定して送信する"
    };

    private final static String TV_NAME[]=
    {
        "注文日時",
        "お問い合わせID",
        "タクシーを呼ぶ場所",
        "個人情報を確認",
        "車両情報を確認",
        "事故写真を撮る"
    };


    private String tabCount[], CAR_KEY_DATA[], PER_KEY_DATA[], times="", local_file="", regId="", cameraPath="";
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private Editor editor;

    private ImageView iv_camera;
    private Button bt_trans[]=new Button[BT_COUNT];
    private TextView tv_trans[]=new TextView[TV_COUNT];
    private TextView tv_order_select;
    private TextView orderDate, orderId, addressData;
    private ListView lv_per, lv_car;
    private Spinner spinner, sp_order_select;
    private Uri mSaveUri, pictureUri;
    private Bitmap picture;

    private boolean imageupsita=false;

    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String>order_adapter;

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>asyncTask=null;
    UploadAsyncTask uptask;

    private PersonOpenHelper hlpr=null;
    private SQLiteDatabase db=null;
    private Cursor c=null;

    private String orders="";


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String strDirPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/";
        Log.v("strDirPath=", strDirPath+"です");
        checkNotNull(SERVER_URL, SERVER_URL);
        checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, SENDER_ID);

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getApplicationContext());
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transmission);

        getPushId();

        sp=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor=sp.edit();

        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_trans11);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        tabCount=new String[sp.getInt("tabCount", 2)-1];

        sp_order_select=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_order_select);
        sp_order_select.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        order_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ORDER_SELECT);
        sp_order_select.setAdapter(order_adapter);
        sp_order_select.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

        for(int i=0; i<tabCount.length; i++)
            tabCount[i]=(i+1)+"台目の自動車で呼ぶ";

        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tabCount);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

        PER_KEY_DATA=new String[PER_KEY.length];
        CAR_KEY_DATA=new String[CAR_KEY.length];

        for(int i=0; i<PER_KEY_DATA.length; i++)
            PER_KEY_DATA[i]=sp.getString(PER_KEY[i], "");

        for(int i=0; i<CAR_KEY_DATA.length; i++)
            CAR_KEY_DATA[i]=sp.getString(CAR_KEY[i], "");

        lv_per=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_per);
        lv_per=EastSys.List2gyou(PER_KEY, PER_KEY_DATA, lv_per, this);
        lv_per=EastSys.ListScroll(lv_per);

        lv_car=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_car);

        orderDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.order_date);
        orderDate.setText(timeData().toString());

        orderId=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.order_id);
        orderId.setText(""+(int)((Math.random()*100)));

        addressData=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address1);
        addressData.setText(sp.getString("getAddress", "住所が選択されていません").toString());

        for(int i=0; i<BT_COUNT; i++)
        {
            bt_trans[i]=(Button)findViewById(BT_ID[i]);
            bt_trans[i].setOnClickListener(this);
            bt_trans[i].setText(BT_NAME[i]);
            bt_trans[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_reca);
            bt_trans[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            bt_trans[i].setTextSize(13);
            bt_trans[i].setWidth(400);
        }
        bt_trans[BT_COUNT-1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_setting);


        for(int i=0; i<TV_COUNT; i++)
        {
            tv_trans[i]=(TextView)findViewById(TV_ID[i]);
            tv_trans[i].setText(TV_NAME[i]);
            tv_trans[i].setTextSize(16);
            tv_trans[i].setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        }

        tv_order_select=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_order_select);
        tv_order_select.setTextSize(16);
        tv_order_select.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

        iv_camera=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_camera);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v==bt_trans[0]) //地図確認
            finish();


        if(v==bt_trans[1]) //個人情報変更
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Transmission.this, Personal.class), 0);


        if(v==bt_trans[2]) //車両情報変更
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Transmission.this, Car.class), 0);


        if(v==bt_trans[3]) //カメラ起動
        {
            imageupsita=false;
            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            pictureUri=getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            cameraPath = getPathUri(this, pictureUri);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, HYAKU);
            imageupsita = true;
        }

        if(v==bt_trans[4]) { //決定送信
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("最終確認")
            .setMessage(order())
            .setPositiveButton("呼ぶ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    editor.putBoolean("呼び出し中", true);
                    editor.commit();

                    if( imageupsita ) {
                        uptask = new UploadAsyncTask( Transmission.this );
                        uptask.context = Transmission.this;
                        String filePath = getPathUri(getApplicationContext(), pictureUri);
                        uptask.execute(filePath);
                        imageupsita = false;
                    }


                    //smsPush();
                    exec_post();
                    SaveDatabase();


                    startActivity(new Intent(Transmission.this, Home.class));
                    finish();
();
                    c.close();
                    db.close();

                }

            }).setNegativeButton("確認し直す", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    return;
                }
            })
            .create()
            .show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {
        if( requestCode == HYAKU && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK )
            iv_camera.setImageBitmap( ( Bitmap )data.getExtras().get( "data" ) );
    }

    protected String timeData()
    {
        Time time=new Time("Asia/Tokyo");
        time.setToNow();
        times=time.year+"年 "+(time.month+1)+"月 "+time.monthDay+"日 "+time.hour+"時 "+time.minute+"分 ";

        return times;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {        
        for(int i=0; i<CAR_KEY.length; i++)
            CAR_KEY_DATA[i]=sp.getString(CAR_KEY[i]+"_"+arg2, "");

        lv_car=EastSys.List2gyou(CAR_KEY, CAR_KEY_DATA, lv_car, this);
        lv_car=EastSys.ListScroll(lv_car);
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}


    private void exec_post() {
        String urls=SERVER_URL+DIR_NAME+FILE_NAME;
        HttpPostTask task=new HttpPostTask(this, urls,

            new HttpPostHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onPostCompleted(String response){
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "完了！", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.v("response="+response, "aaa");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPostFailed(String response){
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "失敗！"+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        );

        for(int i=0; i<PER_KEY.length; i++)
            task.addPostParam(PER_KEY[i], PER_KEY_DATA[i]);
        for(int i=0; i<CAR_KEY.length; i++)
            task.addPostParam(CAR_KEY[i], CAR_KEY_DATA[i]);

        task.addPostParam("REG_ID", regId);
        task.addPostParam("orderId", orderId.getText().toString());
        task.execute();
    }


    private void getPushId(){
        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
        Log.v("regId="+regId, "あああ");
        if( regId.equals("") ) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(Transmission.this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            final Context context = this;
            asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
                    boolean registred = ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);
                    if (!registred) GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute( Void result ){
                    asyncTask = null;
                }
            };
            asyncTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        if(asyncTask!=null) asyncTask.cancel(true);
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name){
        if(reference==null){
            throw new NullPointerException(getString(R.string.error_config, name));
        }
    }


    public static String getPathUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }


    private void SaveDatabase(){
        hlpr = new PersonOpenHelper(this);
        db = hlpr.getWritableDatabase();
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+PERSON_TB, null);

        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();

        for(int i=0; i<PER_KEY.length; i++)
            val.put(PER_KEY_DB[i], PER_KEY_DATA[i]);

        for(int i=0; i<CAR_KEY.length; i++)
            val.put(CAR_KEY_DB[i], CAR_KEY_DATA[i]);

        val.put(HISTORY_TITLE[0], addressData.getText().toString());
        val.put(HISTORY_TITLE[1], timeData());
        val.put("CAMERA_PATH", cameraPath);
        val.put("ORDER_SELECT", sp_order_select.getSelectedItem().toString());
        Log.v("sp_order_select = ", "です" + sp_order_select.getSelectedItem().toString());

        db.insert(PERSON_TB, null, val);
        Log.v("CCC1", "111");
        c.close();
        Log.v("BBB1", "111");
        db.close();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        }
    };

    private String order(){
        String setOrderTitle="";
        String address = addressData.getText().toString();
        String select = sp_order_select.getSelectedItem().toString();

        switch (sp_order_select.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
        case 0: // 事故が起きた
            setOrderTitle = address+"にタクシーを手配します、よろしいですか？";
            break;

        case 1: // B/J
            setOrderTitle = address + "にB/Jをします、よろしいですか？";
            break;

        default :
            setOrderTitle = address + "に" + select + "します、よろしくお願い致します。";
        }
        return setOrderTitle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform the following check before calling `dialog.show()`:

```
    if(!isFinishing){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("最終確認")
            .setMessage(order())
            .setPositiveButton("呼ぶ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    editor.putBoolean("呼び出し中", true);
                    editor.commit();

                    if( imageupsita ) {
                        uptask = new UploadAsyncTask( Transmission.this );
                        uptask.context = Transmission.this;
                        String filePath = getPathUri(getApplicationContext(), pictureUri);
                        uptask.execute(filePath);
                        imageupsita = false;
                    }


                    //smsPush();
                    exec_post();
                    SaveDatabase();


                    startActivity(new Intent(Transmission.this, Home.class));
                    finish();
();
                    c.close();
                    db.close();

                }

            }).setNegativeButton("確認し直す", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    return;
                }
            })
            .create()
            .show();
    }
```

You have to check for that since you cannot attach a dialog to an activity that is not in a proper state for that.

Comment: Hi thank you Adrian!! Coding my Code!, But i don't know. what's Check dialog?

Comment: you cannot show a dialog if it cannot be attached to an activity, i.e. that activity is in an improper state. If my answer helped you please consider accepting it. Thanks!